# The expression "d'office"

Tags: expressions

> Mais il ne faut pas porter des vêtements suggestifs pour gagner, quand même ? Je pense que ça me disqualifie **d'office**.

I’m trying to pin down the meaning of "d'office". Does it mean "automatically (as specified by the rules)", or is it more like "straight away / immediately"?

> = "It wouldn’t do for me to wear some skimpy outfits to win, though, right? If I did, I would be disqualified (**???** = d'office)."

In what other context, would you use "d'office"?

Comment: "D'office" = automatically, "d'emblée" = immediately

Comment: As for usage, "un juge lui a été commis d'office car il n'avait pas d'argent." It appears to be evident that it doesn't mean immediatly but automatically/by default. Sometimes the automatic thing coincidently also happens immediatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the idea. Actually it mean both: automatically (by the rules) and straight away / immediatly. There is nothing to say, and no matter what happens around it, you won't be able to get back in the competition.
It emphasises the **violent** aspect of the disqualification (without negative connotation). To give a precise example about Judo, rules recently changed so one must not put his hands on his oppenent's pants. If so, he is "disqualifié d'office".

I think you may use "direct" or "directement" as équivalents as follows (from less formal to more formal):

> Si tu fais mal à l’adversaire, tu es disqualifié **direct**.
>   Si tu fais mal à l’adversaire, tu es disqualifié **d'office**.
>   Si vous faites mal à l’adversaire, vous êtes **directement** disqualifiés.

An other context where you use "d'office" would be "un avocat commis d'office", where the law states that if you don't want to pay for a lawyer, the State will assign a free one to you. I don't see any other usage of "d'office"...

Comment: Which makes me wonder, by the way... Is the adverbial use of "direct" in place of "directement" a colloquial expression? As in "*je préfère
rentrer **direct** me coucher*". Merci, Random.

Comment: Yes, "*direct*" is informal when used in place of "*directement*". It's shorter so it has naturally replaced his longer counterpart in familiar conversations, I mean we're talking two syllables here !

Comment: I'd add that "*d'office*" is the word of choice for contests, exams, interviews, etc. It has a sense of strictness and unforgiveness  that really fits that sort of things.

Answer (score 0):

d'office:

- automatiquement
- en vertu d'autorité
- en vertu des obligations

A l'origine, il s'agissait d'une charge, d'où les sens précédents.

voir le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/office)